Why did the Maharaja reject the British durai's offer?
In the tale The Tiger King by Kalki see a particular paragraph in the III part of the story which reads:

At another time he was in danger of losing his throne. A high-ranking British officer visited Pratibandapuram. He was very fond of hunting tigers. And fonder of being photographed with the tigers he had shot. As usual, he wished to hunt tigers in Pratibandapuram. But the Maharaja was firm in his resolve. He refused permission. "I can organise any other hunt. You may go on a boar hunt. You may conduct a mouse hunt. We are ready for a mosquito hunt. But tiger hunt! That's impossible!"
The British officer's secretary sent word to the Maharaja through the dewan that the durai himself did not have to kill the tiger. The Maharaja could do the actual killing. What was important to the durai was a photograph of himself holding the gun and standing over the tiger's carcass. But the Maharaja would not agree even to this proposal. If he relented now, what would he do if other British officers turned up for tiger hunts?

I do not understand the last few lines. The British officer only needed a photo with the carcass and the Maharaja would do the killing. Why did he reject this offer? There was no loss for him. He would have killed the tiger himself and the officer would have got the photo and left happily. The story further states that he rejected the offer because other British officers would also come with the same demand, but it should be okay because they only wanted a picture. Why is the Maharaja not agreeing to even this demand?
Here's the story:
https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/levt102.pdf

The Maharaja wants to be sure to reach the magic number of one hundred tigers. So he has decreed that only he himself can kill tigers in Pratibandapuram. Allowing the British officer to kill a tiger would violate this decree. While this officer might be satisfied with just a photo that would falsely suggest that he was the hunter, other British officers might not be satisfied with this ploy; they might want to shoot a tiger themselves.
If and when that happens, the Maharaja cannot tell the other British officers that it was he, rather than the officer, who actually shot the tiger. It would be impolitic to do so; he would have to maintain the fiction that the officer had shot the tiger. This would make it difficult to refuse the other officers when they ask for a tiger hunt, since he has no grounds to make an exception for him but not the others. So the Maharaja thinks it best to reject the offer.
